# Hot to see if some elements are in a list and their position?

Tags: python, list, intersection

If i have two lists like these :

```py
L1= ["A","B","C","D"]
L2=["A","C"]
```

I would like to know if L2 elements are in L1 and their position i.e. A= [0,0] and C=[0,2]. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at the *list* datatype's built-in *index()* function

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!

I think you meant C=[1,2]

this is my code:(I hope its good and helps you :))

```
L1= ["A","B","C","D"]

L2=["A","C"]

for i in range(0,len(L2)):
    for j in range(0,len(L1)):
        if L1[j] == L2[i]:
            print(f"{L2[i]} [{j},{i}]")
```

output:

```
A [0,0]
C [2,1]
```